# Selenium Webdriver : Trying to get text, but specific class present

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

Kindly find attached the html code of the section in question
[image]

I use the following code and managed to get the text for Status

```
successMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='status-success' and @data-v-5d062b04 ='']")).getText();
```

However, I need help to get the number of the Transaction Number field (ie, the 12267A.......) . I can get the successMessage because there is a specific class for it, called
`class = "status-success"`. There is no such specific identifier for the transaction Number which I can use to extract the numerical text.

Hope to havce advice on how to extract the actual trans number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you shared, I was able to get the `Transaction Number` with this line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='status-success' and @data-v-5d062b04 ='']//ancestor::body/div/div/span[@data-v-5d062b04 =''][1]")).getText()
```

Referring your screenshot I tried to recreate the HTML:

```
<div data-v-5d062b04 class="row my-2" style></div>
    <div data-v-5d062b04 class="row my-2" style>
        <div data-v-5d062b04 class="card-item-title col-sm-4">" Transaction Number "
            <!---->
        </div>
        <div data-v-5d062b04 class="col-sm-8">
            <span data-v-5d062b04>12267A2CCM1X4BE9FA5E3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5d062b04 class="row my-2" style>
        <div data-v-5d062b04 class="card-item-title col-sm-4">" User Information "
            <!---->
        </div>
        <div data-v-5d062b04 class="col-sm-8">
            <span data-v-5d062b04> 778478932 (QAColombia#3335) </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5d062b04 class="row my-2" style>
        <div data-v-5d062b04 class="card-item-title col-sm-4">" Status "
            <!---->
        </div>
        <div data-v-5d062b04 class="col-sm-8">
            <span data-v-5d062b04 class="status-success"> Successful </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then used this ***Selenium + java*** code to get the data:

```
String successMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='status-success' and @data-v-5d062b04 ='']")).getText();
if(successMessage.contains("Successful")) {
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='status-success' and @data-v-5d062b04 ='']//ancestor::body/div/div/span[@data-v-5d062b04 =''][1]")).getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Can you advise me, if using @class = 'status-success' wouldn't that just point to the element in "Status" only ? How does it relate to Transaction Number ? Thank you for your guidance

Comment: Oh, i think i see it. It points to the grouping where it consist of SuccessMessage, and then find the Trans Number within the group ?

Comment: What I did is, find the success element, then found a common ancestor of that element. then I traversed to the transaction number. So hope this helped you.

Comment: It did. Thanks a lot

Comment: By the way, does the '1' in "ancestor::body/div/div/span[@data-v-5d062b04 =''][1]"))." 
 refers to the 1st digit of the transaction number ? If that is the case,   what if the transaction number does not necessarily start with "1" ? It could be a random number number of alphabet because it's a unique ID and it will be randomly generated.  Really appreciate your advice

Comment: The [1] is the index of the element. In your HTML there are more than one <span> with similar attributes. So the [1] gets the first appearance of the <span> with matching conditions.

Comment: Got it. Appreciate your guidance.